# Why is more disk storage take up when save the same data into MySQL compared to ‘.mat’ file?

Tags: mysql, database, matlab

for the same data, I first save it as '.mat' file on Matlab and it takes up 2.31M; and then save it into MySQL: 9.85M; 
I want to save it(or them,there are many) into MySQL, and how shall I make them smaller?

update---------------
I use python to save sql file as below code:
"cur.execute('create table if not exists test(date date,open float,close float,high float,low float,vol bigint,turn float)')
        cur.executemany('insert into test values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)', np.column_stack(Matrix).tolist()) ";
In the fact, I need many tables like table "test"; and I just want to save the data and next time I would read out one by one table; and do some other things by python; I want to save each table as small as possible; so any adivice about this?

Comment: A) Why is 9MB a big deal when they sell 10TB hard drives? B) Matlab and MySQL have almost nothing in common, so why should they behave the same way? C) What are you saving and how? No schema is shown here. If you're Base64 encoding your binary file it *will* be bigger.

Comment: I don't know much about MySQL but don't .sql files use an uncompressed ASCII format? That alone would imply they would be much less space efficient than .mat files which are binary.

Comment: thank you for your comments; 1. I save many tables in fact and each is 9.85M is big;2. My computer is x64 and I install sql x64 too; 3. I use python to save sql database as below: "cur.execute('create table if not exists test(date date,open float,close float,high float,low float,vol bigint,turn float)')
        cur.executemany('insert into test values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)', np.column_stack(Matrix).tolist()) "